# How to read while reading from a file in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

i want to use read cmd in a while that read line per line from a file, but i have a problem in line 4 in this script :

```
while read a
do
    echo before
    read var
    echo after
done < file1
```

the result is :

```
before
after.
```

Can you help me to fix this problem????

Comment: Please show us the actual error.

Comment: Where do you want the `read` inside the loop to read from?  The termimnal (even if I/O is redirected from a pipe or file)?  From the standard input of the main script?  @kojiro has given you a decent answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A file descriptor can really only point to one file at a time. Every invocation of `read` you have there reads from standard input, including the one in the middle. If you want to `read` from something else, you have to tell `read` to use another file descriptor.

```
exec 5< file1 # assign file1 to the file descriptor number 5.
              # ("open for reading" as it were)
while read <&5 a; do # read from fd5
  echo before
  read var # read from fd0
  echo after
done
exec 5<&- # Reset fd 5 ("close the file" as it were)
```

You can also use `read -u 5` to read from a specific descriptor in bash.

Comment: You might consider documenting the `read <&5` alternative for folks not using bash.

Comment: Should you add `exec 5<&-` after the loop for symmetry and to clean up?  Clearly, if the script is about to exit, it is far from critical, but closing that which you open is generally a good idea and avoids resource leaking/exhaustion.

Comment: I'd consider scoping the redirection to the loop, rather than starting it prior and needing to clean up after. (`while ... done 5< file1`)